# Mongoose save date in ddmmyyyy format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, momentjs

I have a few fields in my mongo database that are of type **Date**.

Using Node and Express I can pull and display the dates using "**moment**" in any format I want.

When I save them back using "**findByIdAndUpdate**" either the date will be reversed or return a not valid error.

```
message: 'Cast to date failed for value "29-12-2018" at path
```

My issue is that the form returns the date back in ddmmyyyy format whereas I think mongo requires the date to be sent back in mmddyyyy format.

There must be a simple solution to this.

Comment: Are you sure MongoDB isn't using [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? `YYYY-MM-DD` is the standard. Everything else is anarchy due to ambiguity.

Comment: Dates are typically stored as numbers in most db's, not in a "format" that humans read, which would be a string. Think the string returned by the form needs conversion to proper date, not reformatted to another string.

Comment: I managed to write the solution to this using the Moment package. See below my final code `router.put("/user/:id", function(req, res){
    req.body.user.weddingDate = moment(req.body.user.weddingDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user, function(err, updatedUser){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.redirect("/admin");
       }  else {
           res.redirect("/admin");
       }
    });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write the solution to this using the Moment package. See my final code in the original post above

```
router.put("/user/:id", function(req, res){
req.body.user.weddingDate = moment(req.body.user.weddingDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.user, function(err, updatedUser) 
{
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
       res.redirect("/admin");
   }  else {
       res.redirect("/admin");
  }
 });
});
```